# How can I align the JLabel to the left of the panel

Tags: java

I want to align all the JLabels to the left side of the panel.  Following is my code, but it doesnt work properly, I dont know why.
           JFrame frame1 = new JFrame("Register a passenger");
            frame1.setVisible(true);
            frame1.setSize(550, 200);

```
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        frame1.add(panel);

        JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Name",SwingConstants.LEFT);      
        JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Activities",SwingConstants.LEFT);

        JButton jbtReg = new JButton("Register");
        panel.add(label1);
        panel.add(text1);
        panel.add(label2);
        panel.add(text2);
        panel.add(jbtReg);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your example, you could use

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
```

But this will align all your components to the left.

You could also consider using a different layout manager or combination of layout managers?

Take a look at [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more ideas

**Updated**

`FlowLayout` (which is the default layout manager for `JPanel`) doesn't give you a lot of options, instead consider trying to use a different layout manager or combination of layout managers, for example...

[image: Layout]

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class LayoutExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new LayoutExample();
    }

    public LayoutExample() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;

            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;

            add(new JLabel("Name:"), gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(new JLabel("Activity:"), gbc);

            gbc.gridx++;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;

            add(new JTextField(10), gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(new JTextField(20), gbc);

            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy++;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
            gbc.gridwidth = 2;

            add(new JButton("Register"), gbc);

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I tried your code, but it still doesnt change any thing. The layout is :Name     Activities            I mean the Activities didnt go to the left of the panel

Comment: The the panel is been placed within a panel who is using the preferred size of the panel, therefore, no change..

Comment: But how can make it changes? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Basically, you can't, the labels are already left aligned, the layout manager is using the preferred size of the components to layout them out, so the labels don't use any more space then they need. Best choice is to use a different layout manager

Comment: Thank you very much, this really helps me a lot for understanding the layout.